# Update one field value with the same constant for all rows of a table... better way for better performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

If I want to update a field with the same value.

For instance, a table T, with severals columns: A, B, C

Is it **better to run** this statement:

```
UPDATE `T` SET `B` = '0';
```

**or** this one:

```
UPDATE `T` SET `B` = '0' WHERE `B` <> '0';
```

I think the first one could be faster (even if I have an index on B)?

If I have **millions of rows**.. will it be **long or really fast** to apply this update?

*(I try to search an existing similar question... but it's quite hard with the keywords I used.. too many different questions... do not hesitate to point me to a good one...)*

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` show for each statement?

Comment: @njk: hum.. I don't know.. not an expert with mysql... I look...

Comment: All depends how many `B = 0` you have. Updating database can be expensive if you have most of the data cached.

Comment: @njk: `EXPLAIN UPDATE`... my server is too old :( _Before MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information only about SELECT statements._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative performance depends on the selectivity of `WHERE B <> 0`.

- No `WHERE` clause will perform a full table scan.
- No index on B will perform a full table scan.
- An index on B with a low selectivity, i.e. many hits will generate a high rate of random I/O, as the rows found in the index are adressed for update. In most systems, this will be a performance bottleneck. If the selectivity is very low, you might end up with a big part of a full table scan, but pseudo-random instead of sequential - this is worst case. This might be optimized out during query plan generation and replaced by a full table scan.
- a high selectivity, i.e. few hits will still create random I/O, but only as little as necessary - this is best case.

So depending on the percentage of rows needing updating, you should chose between a full table scan (= no `WHERE`) and a targeted approach (= `WHERE` with index)

Comment: Thank you for the different scenarii

Answer (score 1):

imho, the first one will be faster...

afaik mysql ONLY updates automatically columns where the value is NOT the target value - so there is a DOUBLE check on "the value" and it will EVER iterate over the rows.
on your second approach it will iterate two times, if there isn't an index it's totally not good to check with where-clause.

Comment: this is exactly what I **think**...

Answer (score 1):

Beside performance you should be aware about the difference in transactual context.

The first option requires MySQL to lock all rows and the second option only requires locks for the rows where `B <> '0'`. With InnoDB MySQL is able to do this when there is an index for `B` present.

When you've concurrent transactions your posted options are not the same. The first guarantees that for every row after commit is `b=0`. The second only guarantees that every row with `b<>0` is set to 0 after commit. But another transaction can change some row with `b=0` to another value concurrently.

So even when you do not care about the different behaviour then you should care about overall performance when you've concurrent transactions. It may be that the first option is faster but it blocks all other transactions accessing this table rows which is not the case for the 2nd option.

Comment: Thanks for these details